# How to use "OR" in <xsl:copy-of select> in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm using XSLT to convert my XML to a new XML:

My XML:

```
<results>
  <result>
    <headline><a href="/bin-private/060_www_example_com/documents/customer-service/durable-power-of-bank.pdf" id="Link_138609900409016" target="_blank" name="Link_1386090409016" >Power of bank (All States Except New York) (PDF)</a>       </headline>
  </result>
  <result>
    <headline>529 – College Investment Plan</headline>
  </result>
</results>
```

My part of XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<content name="title">
          <xsl:copy-of select="headline/a/text()" />
        </content>
</xsl:template>
```

I want to copy all of the headline value in my title field. But right now only headline/href/a value is getting copied to my title field.
The output which I am getting is:

```
<content name="title">
Power of bank (All States Except New York) (PDF)
</content>
```

Expected output:

```
<content name="title">
Power of bank (All States Except New York) (PDF)
</content>
<content name="title">
529 – College Investment Plan
<content>
```

How should I construct my `<xsl:copy-of select>`? Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: for your expected output you need to handle with "template match result" rather than xsl:copy-of select

Answer (score 0):

One of possible solutions:

```
<xsl:template match="result">
  <content name="title">
    <xsl:value-of select="string-join(headline//text(),' ')"/>
  </content>
</xsl:template>
```

As you wrote, we start from getting all headline values (I assume, you want all **text** values in child *headline* node).
Double slash ensures that all text nodes will be taken, regardless of their depth.

As there can be multiple such nodes (not 1) it is better to use *string-join* with *space* separator.

Comment: It says "xmlPathCompOpEval: function string join not found"

Comment: Maybe you are using XSL version 1. Use version 2. Before I posted this solution I checked it using online XSL verifier. One more remark: You wrote _string join_ with a space. This function has name _string-join_ with a hyphen.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience i never used `<xsl:copy-of select="text()"/>`. Yeah it is possible, but i can't image why would it be useful.

**One alternative approach, even it does not fit the topic-title:**

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/results/result/headline"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="headline">
    <content name="title">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </content>
</xsl:template>
```

**(your expected) result:**

```
<content name="title">Power of bank (All States Except New York) (PDF)       </content><content name="title">529 – College Investment Plan</content>
```

Now, the work is done by a *template-match* for each `headline`. `<xsl:value-of select="."/>` returns only text-nodes, recursively for all child nodes.

Comment: A sublte diffrence occurs if a *headline* tag has **both** href and text content, e.g. *<headline><a href="/xx/yy">Power</a>xx</headline>*.
Then your solution (*select="."*) gives *Powerxx* - both strings glued together. But if you use *select="string-join(.//text(), ' ')"* you get *Power xx* (with a separating space). Note that in this case *.//text()* returns a **sequence** of strings, which can be joined. But if you omit *//text()* then a "." alone retrieves **internally** all descendant text nodes, glues them tohether (without any separator) and returns as a **single** string.

Comment: @Valdi_Bo To be honest with you, there is nothing about glueing text in the question. Question is about to get 2 separate nodes named `content` with only the text-elements of source `headline`. That's all i understand.